# How to `extern alias` an assembly with .Net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

**TLDR**: Everything is pretty much in the title.

Suppose that your `project.json` uses two packages that have a two types which are named the same (same name, same namespace).

How to use one of thoses types ?

With classing .Net, that's easy. Just use an [**extern alias**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/).

But **how do you do that using .net core** ? 
I dont see any option in `package.json` that would let me define an alias like I would do in an assembly reference property window.

The only mention of this issue i managed to find is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/14)

**[edit]** It seems that there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the issue you are trying to link to is here:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989

You can workaround by using an MSBuild Target. drop this snippet into `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Target Name="AddPackageAliases" BeforeTargets="ResolveReferences" Outputs="%(PackageReference.Identity)">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AliasPackageReference>@(PackageReference->'%(Identity)')</AliasPackageReference>
        <AliasName>@(PackageReference->'%(Alias)')</AliasName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)'=='$(AliasPackageReference)'">
            <Aliases>$(AliasName)</Aliases>
        </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

and then use it in your csproj in your PackageReference nodes like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" Version="1.2.6" Alias="signed" />
</ItemGroup>
```

added this as a comment to the GitHub issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-426666530

Comment: yep, that was the issue. i editted my question. 
I did not test your solution, but it looks like something that works, i'll accept that :)

Comment: were is it the "Directory.Build.targets"?

Comment: Were is it "Directory.Build.targets', in which file?

Comment: `Directory.Build.targets` is an MSBuild file you create in you solution dir. if it is present, it will get loaded into your build. if you only need this in one project, you can add it to your `csproj`, but if you have multiple projects, adding it into this file will allow it to be used from any project in your solution.

Comment: @davethieben could you please complete your answer? After creating the `Directory.Build.targets` and setting the alias (`signed`) in my `.csproj` I'm trying to do `extern alias signed` in a C# file but it's not recognized by the compiler. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: make sure it's the first line in the file, or I was seeing: `An extern alias declaration must precede all other elements defined in the namespace`. then fully qualify the Type declaration like `signed::Namespace.Type myType`

Comment: @davethieben Ok I closed and reopened VS then I was doing some testing with a `<Message Text="%(PackageReference.Alias)" Importance="high" />` and then at some point it started working. Beside that I honestly don't know what did I do to solve the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And then it stopped working when I switched Git branch and did it on the library I want. So weird can't explain it for the moment. I will figure this out another time, this task has been postponed anyway...

Comment: @davethieben I'm getting the below error and unable to solve. Could you please help Error CS0430: The extern alias 'signed' was not specified in a /reference option

Answer (score 7):

I had a problem in .Net Core 2.2 where the `MySqlConnector` type name and namespace had a collision and the answer was to create an alias.  I think this should work for your needs too, just change `MySqlConnector` below accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686823/479701

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'MySqlConnector'">
        <Aliases>MySqlConnectorAlias</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

then in your cs file before usings:

```
extern alias MySqlConnectorAlias;
```

then reference your type like this:

```
MySqlConnectorAlias::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for all these workarounds anymore. You can now use `alias` in dotnet from v16.7+. [Details here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-643405754).

So none of the workarounds here are required anymore. Simply add the alias into your project file (intelli-sense didn't seem to think this existed but it works):

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="Example.csproj" Aliases="ExampleAlias" />
```

then use the `extern alias ExampleAlias;` code as you would for .Net framework:

```
extern alias ExampleAlias;

using ExampleAlias::Namespace;
```

and everything works. [Docs for that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#packagereference-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this at the moment. Feel free to file an issue in dotnet cli repo https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in this way:

```
extern alias Lib1;
extern alias Lib2;
using System;
using SpaceOne=Lib1::Space;
using SpaceTwo=Lib2::Space;
```

Example you can find here: https://github.com/ernado-x/owl/blob/master/src/Owl/Program.cs

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is missing information on how to setup the alias in the csproj