# The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 'MySql.Data Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependencies, nuget

I have Referenced `MySql.Data` on one project and Other project referenced nuget package which also referenced `MySqlConnector` inside of it. projects has dependency .

when i compile application im getting this error

[image]

This is application hierarchy

[image]

is there any way to avoid this? or did i do anything wrong when referencing packages?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
this is the same namespaces from difference libs

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

This is the [sample repo](https://github.com/empitegayan/ReposroduceIssue) which reproduced same issue

Comment: Either use the fully qualified type name, or a ```using``` qualifier at the head of the cs file to disambiguate.

Comment: @Matt thanks. problem is both have same namespaces please have a look i have updated post.

Comment: Well then how is the compiler meant to know which one to use?

Comment: @ChrisL good question well that's the my problem as well

Comment: If you google "c# type exists in both assemblies" - you will find a lot of questions about the same issue. If nothing from those questions help - please include what you tried in question.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use both libraries?

Comment: Actually `MySqlConnector` is referenced inside `Identity.Dapper.MySql` i have no way to avoid installing it

Comment: Did you try closing the solution, deleting .suo file and reopening the solution and building?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani yes i did. no luck

Comment: @Gayan can you use same version for both of these assemblies, it might be due conflict of different versions?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani  that's not possible because `MySqlConnector` is in `Identity.Dapper.MySql` nuget and other one inside `MySql.Data` nuget

Comment: @Gayan then maybe you will have to place settings in config file for range of versions for both of these assemblies?

Comment: No luck i believe i this documentation has something related to my problem but don't know how exactly it is 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `NET.Framework` projects you can go to the reference properties and set an alias for assembly. `Net core` projects doesn't fully support yet aliases for assemblies. But there is a workaround to use aliases in `.net core`. Edit your `csproj` file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
...

  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'MySqlConnector'">
        <Aliases>MySqlConnectorAlias</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
...
</Project>
```

then in your cs file before all usings:

```
extern alias MySqlConnectorAlias;
```

then you can reference to you type from `MySqlConnector` like this:

```
MySqlConnectorAlias::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
```

Comment: Hi Albertk, I am trying to use your suggestion in my code as: `MySqlConnectorAlias::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mysql =
                new MySqlConnectorAlias::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();`and then get the error `Cannot resolve symbole MySql`. MySql.Data.MySqlClient are all read in my case. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: It is hard to say for sure. Are you using Resharper? If yes then try to follow answers given here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227523/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678779/why-do-i-get-an-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-symbolname-in-resharper), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654852/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-when-the-code-well-compiled)

Answer (score 1):

It will work If you remove `mysql.data` reference from Your project/references.

Hope it will work for you. for me it was worked. My project is ASP.NET Core Framework. Created project in VS2017 and opening in VS2019 at that time it introduced.